# Pulseaudio unkown PCM pulse

Tags: alsa, streaming, pulseaudio

Using IceS for Icecast when I try to record from "pulse" device I get this error when I start IceS:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM pulse
```

And the program quits.

Here is my .asoundrc:

```
pcm.mmap0 {
        type mmap_emul;
        slave {
                pcm "hw:0,0";
        }
}

pcm.pulse { type pulse }
ctl.pulse { type pulse }
pcm.!default { type pulse }
ctl.!default { type pulse }
```

My icecast.xml input block

```
<!--    Input module.

    This example uses the 'alsa' module. It takes input from the
    ALSA audio device (e.g. line-in), and processes it for live
    encoding.  -->
<input>
    <module>alsa</module>
    <param name="rate">44100</param>
    <param name="channels">2</param>
    <param name="device">pulse</param>
    <!-- Read metadata (from stdin by default, or -->
    <!-- filename defined below (if the latter, only on SIGUSR1) -->
    <param name="metadata">1</param>
    <param name="metadatafilename">test</param>
</input>
```

I can hear audio from the headphone jack.

Any help is much appreciated